# How do I get the current step size of a chartjs chart whose stepSize I have not defined?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

For example, after the chart has been defined, I want to know the stepsize of the y axis.

```
// Your average chart
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {

    type: 'line',


    data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },


    options: {}
});
```

Can I do something like the following?

```
console.log(downChart.options.scales.yAxes.ticks.stepSize);
```

[Here you can see what a stepsize is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELrlW.png)

sources: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings

Comment: what is the output you are getting? what is the error?

Comment: I get no output. But my console.log works fine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can get the number of the stepSize directly, but with

`chartVariable.scales['y-axis-0'].ticksAsNumbers`

you get an array with all ticks. With this you can easily get the stepSize.

**Edit:** `chartVariable` is `chart` in your specific case.

Comment: How can i console log that value in javascript?

Comment: console.log(chart.scales.y-axis-0.ticksAsNumbers).

Comment: Did you manage it? If yes, you can accept this answer so others people don't have to answer this question again.

Comment: No, I couldn't make that value appear in the console that way. I had already tried it that way myself. With "y-axis-0" he has trouble if I use the dot notation inside the console log to reach the value. I also used brackets notation, but it still doesn't work... .

Comment: Strange. Do you have a JSFiddle or something similar?

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake. You have to use the bracket notation with a string inside. I updated my answer.

Comment: Well done. I had made a mistake in my bracket notation attempt.

Comment: It works, but this doesn't seem supported by chartjs, dependig on internal implementation. I wouldn't recommend it for production code (unless you fix the chartjs version in your `package.json` or similar dependency def.